# Printing Error with Subtractions

Tags: java, loops, random, printing, subtraction

I am trying to see what the problem here is. Basically, after ctr = 10, 100, 1000, and 10000, the program is supposed to subtract sumOfCutoff from sumOfRand and also subtract sumOfRounded from sumOfRand and then print both. But for some reason, its not printing both lines, or doing the correct subtraction. The addition parts of the problem is right, but the subtraction part is where I am having trouble.

Does anyone see anything wrong?

```
    int ctr;
    for(ctr = 0; ctr <= 10000; ctr++);
    {
    Random rand = new Random();
    double A1 = rand.nextDouble();
    double A2 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e3) / 1e3;
    double A3 = (double)Math.round(A1* 1000) / 1000;
    double A4 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e4) / 1e4;
    double A5 = (double)Math.round(A1* 10000) / 10000;
    double A6 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e5) / 1e5;
    double A7 = (double)Math.round(A1* 100000) / 100000;
    double A8 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e6) / 1e6;
    double A9 = (double)Math.round(A1* 1000000) / 1000000;

    System.out.println("The accumlators are:");
    System.out.println(A1);
    System.out.println(A2);
    System.out.println(A3);
    System.out.println(A4);
    System.out.println(A5);
    System.out.println(A6);
    System.out.println(A7);
    System.out.println(A8);
    System.out.println(A9);
    System.out.println();

    double sumOfRand = (A1 + rand.nextDouble());
    double sumOfCutoff = (A2 + A4 + A6 + A8);
    double sumOfRounded = (A3 + A5 + A7 + A9);

    System.out.println("The residuals after the 10th time are:");       
    if(ctr == 10)
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("The residuals after the 100th time are:");
    if(ctr == 100)
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("The residuals after the 1000th time are:"); 
    if(ctr == 1000)
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("The residuals after the 10000th time are:");
    if(ctr == 10000)
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
    }

}
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    double A1 = rand.nextDouble();
    double A2 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e3) / 1e3;
    double A3 = (double)Math.round(A1* 1000) / 1000;
    double A4 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e4) / 1e4;
    double A5 = (double)Math.round(A1* 10000) / 10000;
    double A6 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e5) / 1e5;
    double A7 = (double)Math.round(A1* 100000) / 100000;
    double A8 = Math.floor(A1 * 1e6) / 1e6;
    double A9 = (double)Math.round(A1* 1000000) / 1000000;

    System.out.println("The accumlators are:");
    System.out.println(A1);
    System.out.println(A2);
    System.out.println(A3);
    System.out.println(A4);
    System.out.println(A5);
    System.out.println(A6);
    System.out.println(A7);
    System.out.println(A8);
    System.out.println(A9);
    System.out.println();

    double sumOfRand = 0.0;
    double sumOfCutoff = 0.0;
    double sumOfRounded = 0.0;      

    int ctr;
    for(ctr = 0; ctr <= 10000; ctr++)
    {
        if (ctr == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("The residuals after the 10th time are:");   
            System.out.println("Cutoff:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff));
            System.out.println("Rounded:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfRounded));
            System.out.println();
        }

        if(ctr == 100)
        {
            System.out.println("The residuals after the 100th time are:");          
            System.out.println("Cutoff:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff));
            System.out.println("Rounded:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfRounded));
            System.out.println();
        }

        if(ctr == 1000)
        {
            System.out.println("The residuals after the 1000th time are:");             
            System.out.println("Cutoff:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff));
            System.out.println("Rounded:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfRounded));
            System.out.println();
        }

        if(ctr == 10000)
        {
            System.out.println("The residuals after the 10000th time are:");
            System.out.println("Cutoff:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff));
            System.out.println("Rounded:" + (sumOfRand - sumOfRounded));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: how funny that this website become a place for people here and learn to be lazy and not doing their homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error #01

You seem to be missing `{...}` around your `if` conditions, for example...

```
if(ctr == 10)
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
    System.out.println();
```

Is actually saying...

```
if(ctr == 10)
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);

System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
System.out.println();
```

When I think you mean is

```
if(ctr == 10) {
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfCutoff);
    System.out.println(sumOfRand - sumOfRounded);
    System.out.println();
}
```

The braces provide context to a group of conditions...

This goes for all you `if` statements...

You could also use `if-else` statements instead...

```
if(ctr == 10) {
    //...
} else if(ctr == 100) {
    //...
} else if(ctr == 1000) {
    //...
} else if(ctr == 10000) {
    //...
}
```

### Error #2

```
for (ctr = 0; ctr <= 10000; ctr++);
{
```

If you look cloesly at the end of the `for` statement, you have have `;`.  This essentially means, loop a 1000 times and ... do nothing ...

Change it to...

```
for (ctr = 0; ctr <= 10000; ctr++)
{
```

removing the `;` at the end of the statement

Comment: When I removed the ; from the for statement, it printed only the "The Accumulators are" part and 9 doubles ALOT of times. It also only printed the "The Residuals after the 100000th time are:" line. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Of course it does.  Everything within the `{...}` after the `for-loop` will be executed.  You are likely only seeing the `100000th` output because of all the rest of the output (there's some 9000 other iterations between the last statement and the previous one).  Try removing the "accumulator" statements...

Comment: Ok so that did print out each "The residuals after nth time are:" statement. But I also needed to print the accumulator statements. Is there a way to include that without having the loops again?

Comment: Are the accumulators suppose to change on each loop?

Comment: Yep. And it is supposed to be added to the original accumulators.

Comment: `A1` through `A9` are been recreated on each loop, from what you just said, I don't think this is what you want...

Comment: Ok maybe I'm not understanding the directions, but it says:

**Use a loop to accumulate the nine numbers 10000 times - at the 10th, 100th, 1000th, and 10000th - print the values stored in the accumulators and the residuals(the differences between the accumulated sum of the real numbers and the sum of the cutoff numbers, and the sum of the rounded numbers**

Comment: Yep, looks like the nine numbers should be outside the loop.  You can't accumulate them if they are changing each time the loop changes

Comment: I added the Random, the Doubles A1-A9, sumOfRand, sumOfCutoff, and sumOfRounded before the for loop. When I run it, it prints out the same residuals each nth time. I know this because on each "nth time", I am using the same name (sumOfRand, sumOfCutoff, and sumOfRounded), which just adds the ORIGINAL numbers. How do I add the 10th time, and then the 100th time, etc.?

Comment: Only the `A1-A9` should be outside.  `sumOfRand`, `sumOfCutoff`, and `sumOfRound` should decleared outside of the loop, but should be initialised to `0`

Comment: Quick question because I dont understand this part. Why would I initialize sumOfRand, sumOfCutoff, and sumOfRound to 0 if they already have been initialized?

Comment: Because if you don't, you would do double accumulation on the first iteration of the loop.  Initialise them to `0` as a starting point and allow the loop to do it's job

Comment: When I initialized them to 0, the residuals part for all of them equaled to 0.0.

Comment: You're not resetting to `0` inside the loop?

Comment: I made an edit to my original post with my current code as of right now. I think I followed everything you said.

Comment: You need to put `sumOfRand = (A1 + rand.nextDouble());`, `sumOfCutoff = (A2 + A4 + A6 + A8);` and `sumOfRounded = (A3 + A5 + A7 + A9);` back inside the loop (the initialise is fine)